# How do i get the value of input type radio using ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, radio-button

I'm done building an app using ionic. I want to add a star rating feature for clients to give feedback on the service they received. I want to use CSS Star Ratings with Radio Buttons. I have implemented the following code:

```
<div class="rating">
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="star5"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="star4"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="star3"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="star2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="star2"></label>
<ion-button (click)="print(event)" slot="start">Rate Provider</ion-button>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of the selected star rating. I have tried using ion-radio-group i does not work with input type radio but it does work with ion-radio

I need help figuring out how to pass the selected value to my typescript file

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for asking such a stupid question. I resolved this by adding click on each element.

```
<div class="rating">
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" (click)="ratingSelected(5)" /><label for="star5"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" (click)="ratingSelected(4)"/><label for="star4"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" (click)="ratingSelected(3)"/><label for="star3"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" (click)="ratingSelected(2)"/><label for="star2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" (click)="ratingSelected(1)"/><label for="star1"></label>
</div>
```

This worked well for me.